# Linear independence of a restriction

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a suspace of a finite-dimensional vectors space $V$. Denote the dual-space of $V$ as $V'$. Denote a restriction of $f$ on $W$ as $f'$.

**Claim:** If $\{f_{i}'\}$ is linearly independent, then $\{f_{i}\} \in W'$ are linearly independent.

Proof: Suppose that $\{f_{i}'\}$ are linearly independent. Then, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}f_{i}' = 0 \implies a_{1} = \dots = a_{n} = 0$. This implies that $f_{i}'(w) \neq
 0$ for all $w \in W$. Since $w \in W$, and $W \subset V$ then $w \in V$.

Any pointers on if I'm heading in the right direction, or how to continue?

Comment: Should read $f_{i}'(w) \neq 0$. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your argument is going to work. Note also that $f'_i(w)\ne0$ for all $w\in W$ is impossible, since $0\in W$; and it will fail for many other elements of $W$ if the dimension of $W$ is greater than 1 (the only way a linear functional can be injective is if the domain is one-dimensional).

Regarding the proof of the claim, the contrapositive is totally straightforward: if $\{f_i\}$ are linearly dependent, then there exist not-all-zero coefficients with $c_1f_1+\cdots+c_nf_n=0$. Then $c_1f_1'+\cdots+c_nf_n'=0$, and so $\{f_i'\}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: If the nonzero quality of $f_{i}'(w)$ is impossible, how may it ever be linearly independent?

Comment: How would that be a problem?

Comment: If we cannot guarantee that it will be nonzero, then it is zero at some point, which will cause linear independence to fail.

Comment: No. $(1,0,0,0) $ and $(0,1,0,0) $ are linearly independent, for instance.